# Express - Separating route handler logic into controllers

Tags: node.js, express

I have seen examples of separating out Express router logic into controller files such as [meanJS](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/articles/server/controllers/articles.server.controller.js)

E.g.

```
var express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router(),
  catalogues = require('../controllers/catalogues');

router.route('/catalogues')
  .get(catalogues.apiGET)
  .post(catalogues.apiPOST);
```

**../controllers/catalogues**

```
var request = require('request');

exports.apiGET = function(req, res) {
  var options = prepareCataloguesAPIHeaders(req);
  request(options, function(err, response, body){
    res.send(body);
  });
};

exports.apiPOST = function(req, res) {
  var options = prepareCataloguesAPIHeaders(req);
  options.json = true;
  options.body = stripBody(req.body);
  request(options, function(err, response, body){
    res.send(body);
  });
};
```

I have not seen any mention of this in the Express docs, so is this just a new way of thinking in terms of keeping the logic separate from the route definitions?

Are there any performance or other other gains achieved by using this approach?

Comment: There's never any performance gain in separating into files (After all, reading files is "expensive"). The gain is in readability and clarity. If it helps you and your team read the code better, use it. If not, don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEAN.js tries to follow the MVC pattern (Model-View-Controller) in the server side and the result is the logic division between mongoose models, server templates, and controllers.

As a way to improve code organization it is common to separate routes and controllers to their own files as well. In a huge app it helps developers to maintain the code.

Regarding performance, I don't believe there's any improvement.